# Eclipse JDT: Is there a keyboard shortcut for opening new editor panes?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, eclipse-jdt, keyboard-navigation

I often use the multi-pane editor feature in Eclipse to view multiple files simultaneously, and find it very strange that there appears to be no way other than [dragging the tab with the mouse](http://eclipseone.wordpress.com/2010/01/04/split-and-view-the-same-editor-side-by-side-in-eclipse/).  Does anyone know if there's a keyboard technique I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting this, I found the [Eclipse Emacs Plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/emacs) that enables key bindings to create new split windows.

Answer (score 0):

1) Go Window > Preferences > Keys

2) type filter text: "New Editor"

3) Assign whatever key combination you prefer.

If you only want to see a file next to another (vertically or horizontally), you can drag the tab to the right or left (or up or down) of the IDE. Placeholders will appear where you can drop the file next to the other and view them simultaneously.

PS: I'm using Kepler but I'm sure it works the same in older versions.

Comment: This doesn't seem to exist on a JDT installation, there is no "New Editor" entry. I'm on Eclipse Photon.